# In which object, lead conversion field mappings stores in Salesforce

Tags: apex, standard-objects, lead-conversion

I have a requirement where I want to do the Lead conversion field mapping using apex code instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you can not update **LeadConvertSettings** using apex directly. You can do this using the metadata API. So you will need to call the metadata API from apex to be able to update this.

[Refer LeadConvertSettings metadata API docs.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_leadconvertsettings.htm)

[Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart.htm)